# CSS only smoothe scrolling movement

Tags: css

Does anyone know how the guys at **http://www.adtech.com/Home/** were able to achieve the smooth scrolling affect at the bottom part of their homepage? It seems this is done using CSS only (no FLASH, no JS).

Note - this is for learning purposes only (not trying to copy anything here). It's just that I've never seen such a "smooth" affect being done with CSS only, and one which works perfectly on all browsers at that...

I'd appreciate it if someone can point me at the right direction...

Comment: It isn't that smooth on my machine. IMO it only appears smoother because it is quite fast.

Answer (score 1):

Actually... they do use JS: http://www.adtechus.com/jscripts/menu_en.js

**EDIT**

Commentor is correct... this is where they are applying the JS:

```
<script src="/js/mootools.v1.11_complete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/highlights.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    var myMenu = new ImageMenu($$('#photo .photo'),{openWidth:600});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Jason. I believe the JS file you're referring to handles the top menu, not the bottom scrolling...

Answer (score 0):

I think you will probably find that this is delivered by the MooTools Javascript framework.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they ARE using Javascript. Mootools by the looks of things.

For what it's worth, if you want CSS only effect that can do this investigate CSS transitions and tranforms for Webkit browsers.